# Using RPM to customize an installed Yocto SDK

Tags: sdk, rpm, yocto

Is it possible to install a .rpm package into an SDK target sysroot after the SDK has been installed?

The 2.0 Yocto Project Application's  Developer Guide Chapter 4 seems to indicate that this can be done, and even provides an example if using opkg for package management.  I can't figure out how to customize my target sysroot when using RPM package management.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -i --root /different/sysroot/  some-package.rpm
```

or even better

```
dnf install --installroot=/different/sysroot/  some-package.rpm
```

Comment: rpm -i --root ... is the command I would expect to run to install a package in a Yocto SDK (sysroot), however the command returns immediately and doesn't install the package.  Looking at the Yocto sysroot, I don't see a /var/lib/rpm folder which makes me question whether or not yocto supports installing rpms into an sdk (sysroot).  The dnf application is installed ass part of the Yocto SDK.

Comment: I meant to say that the dnf application is *not* installed as part of the Yocto SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the eSDK you can do this using the `devtool sdk-install` command. You can search for candidates with the `devtool search`

For example, if you have added boost to your distribution via `IMAGE_INSTALL` you would have to install the boost libraries this way after installing the eSDK and sourcing the environment.